# How to test every method of a service separately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have a service which calls the API. I already created a test which tests the general paradigm of the service but I need to test method by method within that service.

This is the service:

```
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import ApiNormalizer from './apiNormalizer';
import Article from '../models/Article.model';
import { ContentWithFacet } from '../types/contentWithFacets';
import EventModel from '../models/Event.model';

export interface ResponseData {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export default class ApiService {
  static makeApiCall = <T>(
    url: string,
    normalizeCallback: <T>(d: ResponseData) => T | any,
    callback: (d: T) => any
  ): Promise<void> =>
    ApiClient.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        callback(normalizeCallback(res.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(`ApiClient ${url}`, error);
      });

  static getHomeArticles = (
    callback: (a: ResponseData) => void,
    limit: string,
    sort: string
  ): Promise<void> =>
    ApiService.makeApiCall<Article[]>(
      `content?type=article&limit=${limit}&sort=${sort}`,
      ApiNormalizer.normalizeArticles,
      callback
    );

  static getEvents = (
    callback: (a: EventModel[]) => void,
    pageCount?: number,
    limit?: number,
    sort?: string
  ): Promise<void> =>
    ApiService.makeApiCall(
      `content?type=event&page=${pageCount}&limit=${limit}&sort=${sort}`,
      ApiNormalizer.normalizeEvents,
      callback
    );
}
```

And this is my test:

```
import ApiClient from './apiClient';
import ApiService from './apiService';

const mockData = {};
const mockError = { message: 'Smth Bad Happened' };

jest.mock('./apiClient', () => {
  return {
    get: jest.fn()
  };
});

const firstCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => data);
const secondCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => data);

describe('apiService', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    ApiClient.get.mockImplementation((url: string) => {
      return Promise.resolve({ data: mockData });
    });
  });

  it('should call api client method', () => {
    ApiService.makeApiCall('testUrl', data => data, res => res);
    expect(ApiClient.get).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(ApiClient.get).toBeCalledWith('testUrl');
  });

  it('should call callbacks consequently', done => {
    ApiService.makeApiCall('testUrl', firstCallback, secondCallback).then(
      () => {
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledWith(mockData);
        expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledWith(firstCallback(mockData));
        done();
      }
    );
  });
});

describe('api service error flow', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    ApiClient.get.mockImplementation((url: string) => {
      console.log('error result');
      return Promise.reject(mockError);
    });
  });

  it('should handle error', done => {
    console.error = jest.fn();

    const firstCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return data;
    });
    const secondCallback = jest.fn((data: any) => {
      return data;
    });
    ApiService.makeApiCall('test url', firstCallback, secondCallback).then(
      () => {
        expect(firstCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
        expect(secondCallback).toBeCalledTimes(0);
        expect(console.error).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(console.error).toBeCalledWith('ApiClient test url', mockError);
        done();
      }
    );
  });
});
```

As you might see above, I am testing only `ApiService.makeApiCall` method, but I would like to test `getHomeArticles` and `getEvents` methods.

Any ideas on how to mock those methods to complete my tests?

Comment: Did you try writing tests for those other methods? What happened? You already know how to mock the external collaborators, as you show with ApiClient, so it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: btw do you call `makeApiCall`  from the outside? if you don't than it's implementation-specific and you should not test that explicitly. for testing `getHomeArticles` mock `ApiClient`'s response and validate if it has been called with expected url + validate that `Promise` been returned is resolved with normalized data.